# How to use compiled webpack files on local server

Tags: javascript, django, webpack

I use

`python manage.py runserver` for django and `webpack-dev-server --mode=development` for template on local development.

My file structure is like this

```
/ -  /myproj/
     /defapp/
     /frontend/dist/
     /frontend/static/
     /frontend/templates/
     /frontend/node_modules/
     /static/
```

Now I was ready for deployment on server, so I did `webpack --mode=production`,

It created the `/frontend/dist` directory....

then,,,How can I use this ?

Just accessing localhost (`manage.py runserver`) but no templates appears.

`GET https://localhost:8008/static/js/dashboard.0c3e9ffe26656a1dd3c7.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Maybe I don't understand the basic idea of webpack...

It uses dev server for development but in production, it doesn't require server? am I correct?

My webpack.config.js is below.

```
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

const entries = {}
for (const fileName of require('fs').readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static', 'entries'))) {
  entries[fileName.split('.')[0]] = `./static/entries/${fileName}`
}

const baseConfig = {
  entry: entries,  
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          chunks: 'initial', 
          name: 'vendor',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'webpack-stats.json',
    }),
  ]
};

const devConfig = merge(baseConfig, {
  mode: 'development',

  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/',
  },

  devServer: {
    client:{
        webSocketURL: 'ws://localhost:3000/ws',
    },
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    //watchOptions: {
    //  ignored: /node_modules/
    //},
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  },

});

const productConfig = merge(baseConfig, {
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/static/'
  }
})

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  return options.mode === 'production' ? productConfig : devConfig
}
```

---

Solution

Add this in django setting.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/dist'),
)
```

then it gathers the file to `/static/` folder when `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Yes, Webpack is a bundler that can transform your source files (input) to another compiled version of it (output) e.g. TypeScript to JavaScript.
So in the end, it's just some static files that you can serve. On top of it while developing you can use `webpack-dev-server` which makes it easier to develop your application. This is not being used in production though

Comment: After compilling, how can use the source file under `dist` directory?

Comment: `publicPath: '/static/'` says that the files saved in `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),` will be served from `/static/`. So the path `/static/js/` looks fine, but the setup running at port `8008` does not seem to be configured to look for the files in `dist/`.

Comment: @t.niese thankyou . I moved the file from `/frontend/dist` to `/static` manually, the file is served....

Comment: Problem is solved I update the article. thankyou !

Comment: @whitebear you should create an answer with the solution instead of adding it to the question. And then accept it.